# ODBC driver for Centos7 and oracle not working

Tags: oracle, odbc, centos7

I'm trying to set up an odbc driver on Centos7 and the connection isn't working.

The error message I'm getting in my IDE is:

```
[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Driver's SQLAllocHandle on SQL_HANDLE_HENV failed (0) (SQLDriverConect)
```

odbcinst.ini contains the following

```
[oracle-driver]
DRIVER=/opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.19.1
Description=oracle driver
trace=No
Server=localhost

.odbc.ini contains
[oracle-driver]
DRIVER='oracle-driver'
SERVER=localhost
Port=1521
databse=oracle
uid=oracle
```

Listener status contains the following:

```
LSNRCTL> status
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Start Date                21-OCT-2019 10:47:04
Uptime                    0 days 5 hr. 20 min. 34 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Parameter File   /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/listener.ora
Listener Log File         /opt/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/localhost/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=ipc)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcps)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=5500))(Security=(my_wallet_directory=/u01/app/oracle/admin/ORCLCDB/xdb_wallet))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "9508ea17840841cde055000000000001" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCLCDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "ORCLCDBXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "orclpdb1" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "ORCLCDB", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

Please may you help?

Comment: tnsnames.ora contains:# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCLCDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCLCDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

Answer (score 0):

try
databse=ORCLCDB (or orclpdb1)
instead
databse=oracle

Comment: thank you, I've just tried that but still getting the same error message!

Comment: plz provide  /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora

Comment: # tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: /opt/oracle/product/19c/dbhome_1/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

ORCLCDB =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCLCDB)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCLCDB =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))

Comment: what service (PDB) u want connect?  ORCLCDB ?

Comment: Yes, ORCLCDB is the one I want to connect

Comment: usualy CDB it is main container. i not sure. but u cant use root container for any tasks..

Comment: and u must provide correct uid=oracle, do u have user "oracle" as database user in ORCLСDB service?

Comment: "oracle" is the user I used to install oracle server on the VM - how can I check if it is a db user in ORCLCDB?

Comment: login to database via sqlplus and ..... https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_8003.htm#SQLRF01503